How to implement a mouse click to select a characterbody2d out of various other characterbodies in the scene and move it with mouse click
I am creating a scene with four player, I want to be able to select each by touching them or clicking on them and then pointing at another location to move only that player out of four other players in the scene. How can I Implement this
I tried getting the global_mouse_positioning and adding click but only works on one of them and I am still not sure how to select a player on click and then add the move function.
